# A value of type 'int' cannot be used

Tags: c#

I'm only learning C# and can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

> Error CS1750 A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'MidpointRounding'

Code:

```
public static double MyRound(double value, int point, MidpointRounding midpointRounding = 1)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof (MidpointRounding), midpointRounding))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(midpointRounding));

    decimal num = (decimal)((double)value);

    try
    {
        num = Math.Round(num, point, midpointRounding);
    }
    catch (Exception exception1)
    {
        Exception exception = exception1;
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error : MyRound", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Hand);
    }

    return (double)((double)num);
}
```

Comment: At what line do you get it?

Comment: you have a clear error message telling you what the offending statement/line is. what do you expect this to do?

Comment: @VisualVincent the error message says it's the function declaration (since it speaks of default parameters)

Comment: @kai : Ok, well I'm not a C# developer, so... But good to know. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last parameter is of type `MidpointRounding`, which is an enum. The only `int` literal you can implicitly assign to an enum is `0`. Your provided a default value of `1`, which is what the compiler complains about.

Use `MidpointRounding.ToEven` instead, if that's what you meant.

Some other observations:

- No need to check if `midpointRounding` is in range, [`Math.Round` will take care of that](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,def1acf99267ac6f,references).
- Don't show message boxes from exceptions, this is not a good approach, it mixes UI code with logic code. You should let the exception propagate, if any.
- You wrote `return (double)((double)num);`, one cast would be enough ;)
- No need to cast `(double)value`, as `value` is already a `double`
- Finally... Casting a `double` to `decimal`, then rounding it with a given method, then casting it back to `double` is *not* a good idea. You'll lose precision, and the midpoint rounding metod will most probably be defeated. Use `decimal` all along if the midpoint rounding method is of importance.